# Realm-js throws exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm

I'm trying to write a little test of realm-js using node.js console, but after insertion of te first string I see an exception:

```
> var Realm = require('realm')
TypeError: utf8 is not a function
at Function.from (native)
at Function.from (native)
at module.exports (/home/hermann/node_modules/realm/lib/submit-analytics.js:92:60)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hermann/node_modules/realm/lib/index.js:70:42)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Anybody can help me with this problem?

UPD. An error occures in realm/lib/submit-analytics.js in this call:

```
    request(`https://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=${Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload), 'utf8').toString('base64')}&ip=1`, 
    () => { /* Analytics failed. Do nothing. */ });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug, you must be using Node.js 4.x? I've created an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/912) to track this -- for now you can just comment out that entire line to make it work for you.